# Как отобразить iconContent для полигона?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

Не отображается iconContent для полигона:

```
for (i in data) {
                var myPolygon = new ymaps.Polygon(
                    {
                        type: 'Polygon', coordinates: [// Указываем координаты вершин многоугольника.
                            // Координаты вершин внешнего контура.
                            data[i][0]
                        ]
                    }, {
                        // Описываем свойства геообъекта.
                        // Содержимое балуна.
                        hintContent: i,
                        iconContent: i,
                    }, {
                        // Задаем опции геообъекта.
                        // Цвет заливки.
                        // iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',

                        fillColor: data[i][1], // Ширина обводки.
                        strokeWidth: 0.5, strokeColor: data[i][2], fillOpacity: 0.5, strokeOpacity: 0.5
                    });

                // Добавляем многоугольник на карту.
                console.log(myPolygon);
                myMap.geoObjects.add(myPolygon);
            }
```

Для меток такой проблемы нет, хотя делаю то же самое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**iconContent** существует только у меток. Список свойств полигонов содержит другой набор параметров. Сравните документацию **properties** для [Placemark](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/Placemark#param-properties) и [Polygon](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/Polygon#param-properties)